# How to strip and include Bokeh object in a Flask app

Tags: javascript, html, flask, bokeh

I'm using Flask to display some plots from Bokeh.

To keep things simpler, here is how I generate the plots:
*myplots.py*

```
from bokeh.embed import components
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

p1 = figure()
p1.line(x, y)

p2 = figure()
p2.circle(x, y)

plots =(p1, p2)

js, div = components(plots)
```

*app.py*

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", js=js, div=div, cdn_js=cdn_js, cdn_css=cdn_css)
```

*index.html*

```
  <body>
    {{js|safe}}
    {{div|safe}}
  </body>
```

So, the `js` and `div` from *myplots.py* are passed to *index.html* via *app.py*.

`js` and `div` from *myplots.py* are:

```
('\n<div class="bk-root">\n    <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="55b2192b-8c09-4c3c-95a0-6526e02edeea"></div>\n\</div>',
'\n<div class="bk-root">\n    <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="26241e60-808a-4df9-826b-376752f9e0aa"></div>\n</\div>')
```

The problem that I have is that `('\n \n \n ...\n)` are printed in the browser, next to actual plots, and don't know how to eliminate them.
Here is an example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plots = (p1, p2)`, Here you are passing 2 figures, so there is two plots in total.

So `js, div = components(plots)` would return javascript as an **escaped string** and div's for both the plots as a **tuple** of length 2 since you have two plots.

When you put `{{ div | safe }}` in the jinja2 template, since the div is a tuple it is not properly displayed.

So inorder to display the tuple, just loop through it,

```
{% for item in div %}
    {{ item | safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Below is the sample script with the fixes,

app.py

```
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    p1 = figure()
    p1.line(x, y)

    p2 = figure()
    p2.circle(x, y)

    plots = (p1, p2) # you are passing 2 plots

    js, divs = components(plots) # divs will contain a tuple of length 2

    return render_template("index.html", js=js, divs=divs)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample</title>

    <link
            href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.13.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
            href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.13.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
            href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.12.13.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.13.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.13.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.12.13.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

{{js | safe}}
{% for div in divs %}
    {{ div | safe }}
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeap, that's it! Cheers! Just a note...I tried to keep that loop in `index.html` and pass in just a single plot, _p1_. In this case, the `{% for...%}` fails to iterate over a single element and prints `< d i v c l a s s = " b k - r o o t " > < d i v c l a s s = " b k - p l o t d i v " i d = " d 8 c e 0 d 9 2 - 4 8 e 0 - 4 a c c - 8 1 5 0 - 7 0 2 e 3 f 6 c 0 d 8 8 " > < / d i v > < / d i v >`. So, the idea is not to touch _index.html_ and having it to support any number of plots that comes in.

Comment: Found out that the fix is to pass in the single plot as a _tuple_, `plots = (p1, )` and that will do it. From here on, I can still keep the `{% for ..%}` in _index.html_ and I can add whatever number of plots I need without breaking the code.